# AWS Step Functions: it doesn't show list of existing roles while creating a new state machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

Issue:

1) I create new AWS State Machine with "Hello World" blueprint

2) click on create state machine button

3) it opens a dialog box and choose iam roles dropdown is empty and is not showing list of existing iam roles associated with my aws account

Debugging:

I found that it throws following JS error while loading dashboard itself before doing anything else.

JS Error:grapheneConsole_prod_963c8da….gz.js:110 POST https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/states/service/iam/createrole 403 (Forbidden)

So i think it assumes the user to have "create role" permission which i don't have.

If anyone faced this before and solved it. Please help me.

**Some extra info**: I am using a corporate aws account which is what is assigned to all developers. Also for lambda or any other AWS resources we have been given specific dev role we are supposed to use and i have successfully used that with everything else along with creating lambda. I would have chosen the same iam role if it would have shown me the list

Comment: check whether policies attached to __dev__ role have sufficient permissions to create state machine ?

Comment: Actually problem here is little different than i thought. Error is because if their bug and because of which it is not able to pull my existing roles. So evenif i had permission to create a role it might behave the same way and will not show drop down of existing roles.
I saw someone had posted on AWS forum the same question and they have fixed the issue but its been one day and i have not got any response on my thread. I might need to wait for sometime.

Comment: ok .. can't do much about it then . please mark my comment helpful if you find it so thanks  -

Comment: You can check MColeTrickle answer. That is the correct one!

Answer (score 8):

I posted about my issue to AWS support.

They have provided the justification of why it is happening. In my opinion it is more of a limitation.

So dropdown to select an IAM role in Step Functions works differently compared to our other services. Only IAM roles that have trust relationship allowing Step Functions service in the region to assume the role will show up in the dropdown unlike our other services. So i need to have at least one IAM role in my account with below trust policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "states.<region>.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope this helps to anyone having similar issue. It took me few days to reach an answer.

Comment: This isn't a limitation. It's a prerequisite for the IAM Role configuration, in order for AWS Step Functions to assume the role for state machine execution.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan "states..amazonaws.com" should be "states.amazonaws.com". And just to further clarify, under your role's summary, you can edit this under "Trust Relationships/Edit Trust Relationship"

Comment: @LandonC I have no idea why you're addressing me, as I didn't provide the mistyped answer. I simply pointed out that this is intended behavior, not a service limitation. Also FYI, you can edit the person's incorrect answer and fix their post for them.

Comment: Man you just saved my miserable day !!! After one day of trying, it worked. Instead of using service: lambda, please use  service: states. Thx man again !!!